# How do I share my Internet connection wirelessly while using it on my MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, internet-sharing

How do I share my Internet connection wirelessly with other gadgets while using it simultaneously on my MacBook Pro?

I am using a Idea Netsetter 3g dongle for broadband Internet access. However, when I go to the settings to share it with other devices, the MacBook Pro is the only one left out of the connection.

Comment: Which OS X version? Have you tried following the procedure explained here: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH3853? Could you make a screenshot of System Preferences>Sharing>Internet Sharing when you try to share the connection (you could use http://imgur.com and paste the link, someone with enough rep will edit your post and insert the picture inline)?

Answer (score 3):

I've used  Idea Netsetter Dongle and shared my internet over the Wifi.

[image]

- First connect to the Internet with Idea Netsetter 3G
- Open System Preferences > **Sharing**
  [image]
- Select the Network which you want to share ( **In your case it's Ethernet Adaptor** )[image]
- Select the network(s) which you want to share the internet to (In your case **Wifi**)
  [image]
- Don't forget to switch you're Wifi On
  [image]
- Now if you look at the Wifi Icon on your Menu Bar , You'll notice something different.

[image]

- Now take any other device ( iPhone , Android Phone , iPad ) and connect to your WiFi Network.

Hope this is what you were looking for !

Answer (score -1):

http://www.4shared.com/file/5-AHKzPA/Marywifi-EN.html
this apps help it's easy and simple to share your wireless

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.